# How to get elements from an array from a index to the end

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Sample Mongo Document

```
chat = { _id: someid, messages: [{text: 'aaa'}, {text: 'bbb'}, {text: 'ccc'}, {text: 'ddd'}] }
```

I need to extract messages starting from index 1 till the end of the array. 
Thanks.

Codes tried so far:

```
let theIndex = 1;
Model.aggregate(
  { $match: condition },
  { $project: { 'chat': { $slice: ['$chat.messages', theIndex, 25]  } } }
)
```

This will give me 25 messages, but i need it to be till the end of the array.

Hope the question is clear.

Comment: Still need clarification on what you want. Also post the code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) as a last `$slice` parameter:

```
let theIndex = 1;
Model.aggregate(
   { $match: condition },
   { $project: { 'chat': { $slice: ['$chat.messages', theIndex, { $size: '$messages' }]  } } }
)
```